# How to find the changed value in history table sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find if the value changed for a particular ID

| ID | PAYMENT METHOD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CASH |
| 1 | VISA |
| 1 | CASH |
| 2 | CASH |
| 2 | CASH |
| 2 | CASH |
| 3 | CHEQUE |
| 3 | VISA |
| 3 | VISA |
| 4 | CASH |
| 4 | CASH |
| 4 | CASH |

For example, ID 1 and ID 3 changed their payment method and I want to write a query that can detect that change, thanks in advance

example for expected output:

| ID | PAYMENT METHOD HAS CHANGED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | VISA |
| 3 | CHEQUE |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: How do you decide to return VISA for ID = 1, and not CASH? Why is CHEQUE returned for ID = 2?

Comment: MTO's answer is probably the best for how you wrote your question. I have a couple of suggestions to possibly get additional and more specific answers.  

First, your example output isn't possible. You list ID 2 CHEQUE, however, ID 2 in the table only has CASH. Any answers will be guessing at what you are trying to accomplish.

Second, your example output only shows 1 payment method per ID. I assume you want the most recent payment method, however, you have no column to order by. If your table has a timestamp it would allow simpler queries to get the latest changed payment method per ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MIN(payment_method) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ROWNUM)
         AS payment_method
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT payment_method) > 1
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         payment_method,
         ROWNUM AS ordering_column
  FROM   table_name t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY ordering_column
  MEASURES
    FIRST(payment_method) AS payment_method
  PATTERN (^ same+ diff)
  DEFINE
    same AS FIRST(payment_method) = payment_method,
    diff AS diff.payment_method <> same.payment_method
);
```

*(Note: `ROWNUM` should be replaced by a column that will identify a deterministic ordering in the rows for each `ID` such as a timestamp column; however, such a column is not present in your sample data so it cannot be used. `ROWNUM` will just number the rows in the order that the SQL engine processes them and that processing order may be non-deterministic.)*

Which both output:

> | ID | PAYMENT_METHOD |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | CASH |
> | 3 | CHEQUE |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=837857dac4ac6c4402d6bcb12dcbb18b)*